# Pyinstaller not packaging python encoding files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
C:\desktop 2\files\Python projects\Pyinstaller testing\dist>test.exe
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\robby\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI30322'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\desktop 2\files\Python projects\Pyinstaller testing\dist\test.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\desktop 2\\files\\Python projects\\Pyinstaller testing\\dist\\test.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\desktop 2\\files\\Python projects\\Pyinstaller testing\\dist\\test.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\robby\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI30322\\base_library.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\robby\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI30322',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread 0x0000204c (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

C:\desktop 2\files\Python projects\Pyinstaller testing\dist>
```

That is the full error after opening an exe I created using pyinstaller --onefile test.py
test.py contains this only

```
import time
input("Test")
print("hello world")
time.sleep(60) #Time.sleep makes the cmd persist
```

After unpacking the .exe file I could see that the encodings folder was missing all of the python encodings which I assume is spitting the error.(it only contains 3 files unrelated to encodings)[The 3 Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqw6r.png) I tried specyfying the path to the encodings module with pyinstaller --onfile --paths="path" test.py to no avail. I also tried importing encodings in my code again issue persisted. Is the issue with the missing files in the unpacked exe? Or is it some other issue? The unpacked exe is [here](https://anonfiles.com/t6ldWb4dp0/test.exe_rar)

Solution: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5438